# Easy way to transfer/update a list of numbers to be used in the SQL 'in' command?

Tags: sql

I'm always being given a large list of say id's which I need to search in our database have manually put them into a sql statement like the follow which can take a while putting single quotes around each number followed by a comma, I was hoping someone has a easy way of doing this for me? Or am I just being a bit lazy...

```
select * from blah where idblah in ('1234-A', '1235-A', '1236-A'  ................)
```

Comment: Which platform? Each one may have a different vendor specific solution. Eg. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [worlds' simplest code generator](http://nimbletext.com/live).

Just paste in the list of values, setup the pattern and voila... you have a set of quoted values.

I have also used Excel in the past, using the CONCAT function with smart paste.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will def save me alot of time :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would set aside a table to hold the values and have my queries `JOIN` against that table. Set up a simple import script (don't forget to clear out the table at the start) and something like this is a breeze. Run the import, run the query. You never have to touch the query again or regenerate any code.

As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Search_ID_List (
    id    VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Search_ID_List PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
)
```

and:

```
SELECT
    <column list>
FROM
    Search_ID_List SIL
INNER JOIN Blah B ON
    B.id = SIL.id
```

If you want to be able to save past search criteria or have multiple searches available to you at the same time then you can just add an identifying column which gets filled in by your import. It can be the file from where the ids came, some descriptive code/name, or whatever. Then just add that to the `WHERE` clause of your query and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
select * from blah where ',' + '1234-A,1235-A,1236-A' + ',' LIKE ',%' + idblah + '%,'
```

This pattern is super useful when you're being passed a comma delimited list of values to filter by, but I think would be applicable here as well.